# $B$ is complete $\iff$ every member of $B$ is a subset of $B$; is there another term for 'complete'?

Tags: set-theory, definition, ordinals

I'm reading Suppes' Axiomatic Set Theory, and this definition is on page 130 when we begin building the ordinal numbers. I can't seem to find any reference on either MathSE or google about complete sets in specifically this sense. Is there another term for it? It likely seems related to order, but I can't seem to find any explicit connection.

[image]

Comment: This is typically called a "transitive set". This is because if we have $x \in y \in A$ then $x \in A$, so the $\in$ relation is transitive-ish.

Comment: @MarkSaving you've been a life-saver for my questions today, thanks a lot!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_set_theory  has it listed as an old term for transitive set and has a bunch more set theory terms that might help you

Comment: @Alan thank you very much!